# Como criar um link deslizante sem JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html5, link

Como posso criar um link âncora deslizante com JavaScript puro para uma página single page?

[Exemplo usando jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/fv1z183c/1/)

Comment: Poderia dar um exemplo concreto do que pretende, e adicionar o código de alguma tentativa, algo parecido?

Comment: @SamirBraga Já coloquei um exemplo! :)